# list index out of range scraped

Tags: python

I am practicing how to scrape data from webpage. While practicing, I had lots of trouble.

Now, I am struggling to figure out the error below.

Is there anyone who knows how to deal with it?

Thank you!

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_rise.nhn")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'tltle'})
results = soup.find_all('tr')
results2 = results[7:1283]

first_result = results2[0]
first_result

records = []
for result in results:
    a = result.contents[1].text
    b = result.contents[3].text
    c = result.contents[5].text[6:-6]
    d = result.contents[7].text[6:-6]
    e = result.contents[9].text   
    f = result.contents[11].text
    g = result.contents[13].text
    h = result.contents[15].text
    i = result.contents[17].text
    j = result.contents[19].text
    k = result.contents[21].text[6:-6]
    l = result.contents[23].text

    records.append[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)]


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-269-8e1cb3b2bf90> in <module>()
      7     e = result.contents[9].text
      8     f = result.contents[11].text
----> 9     g = result.contents[13].text
     10     h = result.contents[15].text
     11     i = result.contents[17].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making an assumption about the number of children in the resulting TR DOM element. There are multiple tables on that page. You either need to limit the search to the specific table you want, and know the number of children to index into, or you can iterate over the children and append them dynamically. You can also handle the IndexError, and ignore the error, however this is bad practice, and you're still not going to be sure as to what elements you're finding on the page.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. The primary problem with your code is that you're trying to access an index that's outside of the range of the TR contents list returned. One options is to make your find_all parameter more specific to return the actual TR values you are expecting, so that you can then apply the correct indexing. Another option would be to iterate over the contents based on the size using something like `for i in range(len(result.contents)):` in order to never go beyond the length of the result.contents list.